# C# DI with generic interface and parameters

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dependency-injection

Given a generic interface and its implementation:

```
public interface IGenericInterface<T> { ... }

public class GenericImplementation<T> : IGenericInterface<T> { ... }
```

I am registering this for DI using
`services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericInterface<>), typeof(GenericImplementation<>));`

This works fine, of course. But I would like to inject a setting/config from the `appsettings.json`, which is where I'm coming unstuck.

Usually, I'd register my dependencies with parameters using `services.AddTransient<IInterface>(x => new Implementation(x.GetRequiredService<IDependency>(), configuration["SomeSetting"]);`

Is it possible to pass parameters to a dependency when registering it by `type`?

Comment: Inject configuration instead of configuration ["foo"]

Comment: I can understand the benefit of injecting the configuration object as opposed to the actual config value, but does that not tie the config setting name to the class it's injected into? Say for instance multiple classes depended on the config setting "foo", is it not better practice to just inject what's required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of the Options Pattern.

You need to bind the config to a class and register the class for DI. Then in the constructor for the class that needs the config, you pass it in via the constructor.

Documentation Here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Completely forgot about that, great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: No problem, there's a great wealth of good Microsoft documentation of design patterns for everything related to .Net Core so it's always good to check there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be injecting your configuration class into your other dependencies' classes, and let them pick out what they want. What you're doing is breaking that separation of concerns.

Comment: "What you're doing is breaking that separation of concerns" How so? If Implementation<T> requires some config to function (lets say its a repo and needs a connection string) why can't I inject it?

Comment: You're not injecting it, you're sending it as a parameter, cherry picking the setting in question with a string. That means that you as the implementer of the setup need to know exactly what string to pass to this thing in order to get the configuration value to then manually pass to your service. What *we* are saying, on the other hand, is to inject the configuration.